# how to restrict focus or allow tab keypress to only selected current tab of p-tabview

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I'm using primeng `TabView` for my requirement.

https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tabview

I have multiple `tabs` and inside each tab, I have multiple HTML controls.

I want to allow `tab` keypress only to selected current tab controls of `tabview`.

Suppose, I have 2 tabs like `City`, `Location` and each tab have multiple has multiple controls in it.

If focus is on `City` tab and when I press `tab` keypress, focus should move to only `City` tab controls and focus should not go to `Location` tab.

I know we can set `tabindex=-1` for other tabs like `Location`, but if we set `tabindex=-1` it will not be selectable again if user want to select `Location` tab.

How to achieve above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the `tabindex` value programmatically, at first put the `tabindex='0'` for your active tab and `tabindex='-1'` for the others then whenever user clicks on the other tab, change its tabindex to `tabindex='0'` and previous active tab to `tabindex='-1'`

Comment: Actually I'm navigating through tabs using keyboard itself, like using Tab and Enter keys. If I set tabindex=-1 for other tabs, then I'll not be able to move to other tabs using tab keypress. How to handle this. I'm working on Accessibility.